# npm install: react-scripts install fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install, react-scripts

I have the following (simplified) package.json file:

```
`{
  "name": "cotd",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}`
```

When I tried to install it with `npm install` it failed several times (first some warnings about deprecated dependencies, and at the end several npm ERR! codes (see below).
I tried to delete the node_modules folder, tried `npm cache clear --force`, none of them helped.
Here is the output of npm install:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path D:\MyEverything\Dropbox\Learning\WesBos\react-for-beginners\catch-of-the-day\node_modules\async\package.json.541798468
npm ERR! dest D:\MyEverything\Dropbox\Learning\WesBos\react-for-beginners\catch-of-the-day\node_modules\async\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'D:\MyEverything\Dropbox\Learning\WesBos\react-for-beginners\catch-of-the-day\node_modules\async\package.json.541798468' -> 'D:\MyEverything\Dropbox\Learning\WesBos\react-for-beginners\catch-of-the-day\node_modules\async\package.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\andra\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-17T19_03_36_237Z-debug.log
```

OS: Win10 home, 64bit
Node: v13.1.0
npm: 6.12.1

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically if node throws lock, rename, delete error that means its trying to rename a resource that has been locked by OS for some reason. I had used cache and prefix option in .npmrc file and it had solved many of my renaming and delete issues for node. Add two entries called 'prefix' and 'cache' and the value for these should be a valid folder path outside of your current folder node modules folder. my points to
`cache = "c:\\workspace\\temp\\npm-cache"
prefix = "c:\\workspace\\npm"`

Comment: thanks for the hint, although it didn't solve my problem, but gave me an idea which lead me to the solution... see below...

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems, that Dropbox synch was the guilty one, that locked something during `npm install` which npm didn't like.
I moved the folder outside from my dropbox folder, and... surprise, surprise... worked like charm.

Now the task is to find a solution to selectively exclude subfolders from synching (dropbox doesn't support a .gitignore-like solution), but this is nothing to do with javascript or node or npm...